# How to return a empty io.Reader?

Tags: go

I have a function which returns an io.Reader:

```
func getData(bucket string, key string) (io.Reader, error) {
  svc := s3.New(cfg)

  req := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
  })

  res, err := req.Send()
  if err != nil {
    // How to return a empty io.Reader here?
    return bytes.NewReader([]byte), err
  }
  return res.Body, nil
}
```

And I would like to know, how to return a empty io.Reader from the err block.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of a non-`nil` error return value, usually other parameters are left to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of their type, which in case of `io.Reader` (which is an interface type) should be `nil`:

```
return nil, err
```

Callers are responsible to first always check the returned error, and only proceed to use other return values if the error is `nil`. This is the general "rule". There may be exceptions of course, in which case you should document the deviant behavior.

Actually there's nothing wrong with providing other values along with non-`nil` errors, and often it's useful. Typical example is the [`io.Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) method, which documents how implementations should (must) work:

> It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.
>
> ... When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read.

So even if `Reader.Read()` returns a non-`nil` error, it also reports how many bytes it was able to read successfully before the error was encountered, so you may process / use up to `n` bytes from the slice.

Comment: Cool! How can I find out this tricks? I did searched but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, that't not a trick, that's a mere common sense ;-) I'd start with [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) and [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, "lurking" is another powerful concept. Subscribe to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) and read interesting discussions; watch (RSS for instance) the `[go]` tag here on SO and watch the answers given by wizards like @icza.

Comment: This is not a trick at all. Just read the io.Reader documentation.